# Submit button appears outside the form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have a small problem of display, I use Bootstrap and I have a panel which serves to fill a field, and which contains the title, the field of entry, and the button of validation. the problem is that the validation button goes beyond the outline of the panel, would you have a solution to that, please,
thanks !

the panel comes from this part of code :

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="panel-footer">
<ul class="list-group">
<?php foreach ($header['children'] as $index => $child) : ?>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
        <?php echo $child['Node']['name']; ?>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group">

                <?php
                    $edit_form = $this->BsForm->create('Node', array('class' => 'form-vertical'));
                    $edit_form .= $this->BsForm->hidden('id', array('value' => $child['Node']['id']));
                    $edit_form .= $this->BsForm->input('name', array('value' => $child['Node']['name']));
                    $edit_form .= $this->BsForm->input(__('Modifier'), array('type' => 'submit', 'class'=>'btn-default'));
                    $edit_form .= $this->BsForm->end();
                    echo $this->element('btn-tree-edit', array('form' => $edit_form));
                    echo $this->element('btn-remove', array('name' => $child['Node']['name'], 'id' => $child['Node']['id']));
                ?>  
</div></div></div></li></ul></div></div>
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: you dont have to everything inside <div class="btn-group"> . Okay.

Comment: To get front-end help, post front-end code. Post the result of your php, not the source. If you add a [mcve] displaying your problem (by using the minimal amount of code from your project, just enough to repro), chances are someone will spot the CSS issue and provide you with the rule that needs to be overwritten. In current form, your question in unanswerable, as the issue cannot be reproduced, making any possible fix untestable.